# Combining earnings report data with customer satisfaction survey data

Tags: references, project-management

There is a popular Kaggle dataset on [airline CSAT](https://www.kaggle.com/teejmahal20/airline-passenger-satisfaction). It is a customer satisfaction survey using features of inflight services and travel procedures such as `Gate Location`, `WiFi Quality`, `Flight Distance`, `Cabin Class`  etc. No one knows for sure, but it's believed to be taken from Delta, American and Alaska.

Since these types of classification datasets are so common, I want to incorporate airline earnings report data to differentiate my analysis from other projects.

How would I approach this? Would it even be possible since the airlines are unknown? Even if the airlines were known, I wouldn't know which data points belonged to which airline and I wouldn't know the years of the survey.

Would I be better off with another source of data? Is this something I can locate by a paid subscription somewhere?

Provided all this would even be possible, what would I be doing exactly? Would I be combining time series data (airline earnings reports) with my CSAT dataset? Earnings reports are only 1-4 quarterly values (not thousands of rows) so how would I use that information in my analysis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to combine two data sets where the date or time is the important key that pairs data from one set to data in the other set.

However, it doesn't seem like time is available in the CSAT dataset. Or at least not in the data-file that is found in your link.

So you can not link the two datasets because they are completely unrelated. It would be like asking how to use the [iris flower dataset](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iris_flower_data_set) to differentiate your analysis.

However, if the CSAT dataset had a date then you could combine the data. But it is doubtful whether it would improve anything.

- Possibly when you have a lot of different airlines or a lot of different times then it might be worthwhile.
- But for a single airline and a short period it doesn't seem adding much information how the earnings fluctuate. If there is some effect of time than something like a random forest algorithm could figure this out as well. Adding the earnings would not make this work better unless you have several airlines and/or a large time period.

Comment: Thanks. Basically my tutor said he wanted me to try to differentiate it from other notebooks by seeing if their earnings reflected the surveys. At least that's what I think he means. As you said, I guess that does not mean combining datasets. Even still, I don't have any time data nor do I know which airlines they are, so I think either way I'm hooped. p.s. Do you know where I could find current paid for datasets that are maybe the actual source for many public Kaggle datasets? These must originate from paid sources right? How does a real-world analyst find these original sources?